# How can i configure Spring Cloud Config Server with refresh functionalities on AWS ECS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ecs, configserver

I am migrating a Spring Boot application from PCF to AWS ECS which is currently using cloud config server reading properties from git repo, and aws RDS. Now in ECS is there a way we can implement config servers along with refresh in ECS AWS.

Answer (score 1):

I think ECS operates on a different level.

Spring Cloud Config server is a solution that works especially good with spring boot based applications. For example, a refresh option that you've mentioned is implemented as a special Scope which is purely a spring (applicative) thing.

On the other hand, AWS ECS (stands for Elastic Container Service) provides a way to work with containers in a general sense (with scaling and everything). It doesn't require the containers to be spring-based or even java based.

So, I think you might want to consider keeping a spring boot driven microservice for config server just like you have now, but wrap it into docker container and deploy it in AWS ECS